Attempting to rewrite (or map) old URIs to new URIs
I want to improve the mapping of a Nexus Repository Manager v2 (NXRM2) URI and redirect it to the equivalent (identical, imported copy) on a Nexus Repository Manager v3 (NXRM3) URI.
NXRM2 URI example:
/nexus/service/local/respositories/myrepo/content/com/acme/dept/sub-dept/team/sware/0.0.1/package.tar.gz
NXRM3 URI example:
/respository/myrepo/com/acme/dept/sub-dept/team/sware/0.0.1/package.tar.gz
I had no issue performing a simple match (and then a proxy pass with an informative header).
However, I now need to do the same for several thousand URIs. From what I have researched online, I understand the recommended solution would be to use regular expressions (regex) and variables and avoid "if" at all costs. Unfortunately, I am not entirely sure exactly where to begin in creating this regex solution to transform the URI, and I was wondering if anyone who managed to achieve something similar can share their attempt.

Without more information maybe: ^\/nexus\/service\/local\/respositories(\/myrepo)\/content(.+)$ and replace with /repository$1$2. See https://regex101.com/r/U86Ycv/latest
